CUDA dynamic parallelism -- Is there a way to infinitely nest kernel launches?
Now, I'm using CUDA dynamic parallelism to create the kernel in a kernel function.
In the CUDA document, kernel functions can only be launched a fixed recursion depth because of resource constraints.
But in my project, I want to launch the kernel but parent kernel doesn't need to wait for exiting of child kernel. In other words, they are completely independent.
So is there some ways to launch the kernel in kernel functions but not limited by recursion depth?
I use the cudaDeviceSetLimit() to set cudaLimitDevRuntimeSyncDepth but there are still restrictions.
Example:
__global__ void do_something(MyQueue* queue, Task* task) {
  // do something ...
  task->execute();

  // If queue is not empty, pop from it and launch a kernel to execute it
  Task* t = queue->pop();
  if (t) {
    do_something<<<t->gridSize, t->blockSize, t->mem, stream>>>(queue, t);
  }
}


GPU: NVIDIA A100
CUDA version: 12.4
compile flag: -rdc=true -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=compute_61


"An optimization is permitted where the system detects that it need not reserve space for the parent’s state in cases where the parent kernel never calls cudaDeviceSynchronize(). In this case, because explicit parent/child synchronization never occurs, the memory footprint required for a program will be much less than the conservative maximum. Such a program could specify a shallower maximum synchronization depth to avoid over-allocation of backing store."

There is a specific reason why you use a recursive approach? If not, I think that a most convenient approach would be to lunch n kernels to fully use the GPU, each of which considering sizeOf(queue) / n  tasks.

CUDA 12 actually introduced a new version of dynamic parallelism (CDP2) that does not allow synchronizing in device code anymore because that was a performance issue. It sounds like you should just launch your kernels using the new cudaStreamFireAndForget.

Thank you, I think CDP2 can solve my problem. I'm coding a runtime system on GPU. Considering the performance and other scheduler strategy, I move the queue to the GPU so I can't launch a kernel on CPU. Now I'm trying the cuda dynamic parallel to solve this problem. :-)

according to my testing, making use of CDP2, it certainly seems possible to launch a kernel that will call sub-kernels for a "long" sequence:
# cat t225.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using mt = int;
const mt my_stopc = 32768;
__global__ void k(mt *d, const mt my_stop){

  mt c = *d;
  if (c < my_stop){
    c++;
    *d = c;
    k<<<1,1,0, cudaStreamTailLaunch>>>(d, my_stop);}
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if (err != cudaSuccess) printf("device: %lu, %s\n", (unsigned long long)c, cudaGetErrorString(err));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  mt my_stop = my_stopc;
  if (argc > 1) my_stop = atol(argv[1]);
  mt *d;
  cudaMallocManaged(&d, sizeof(d[0]));
  *d = 0;
  k<<<1,1>>>(d, my_stop);
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  if (err != cudaSuccess) std::cout << "host 1: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
  err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  if (err != cudaSuccess) std::cout << "host 2: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "iter: " << *d << std::endl;
}

# nvcc -o t225 t225.cu -arch=sm_89 -rdc=true -lcudadevrt -lineinfo
# ./t225
iter: 32768
# ./t225 70000
iter: 70000
#

CUDA 12.2, L4 GPU
If I increase the count to 1000000, then the (parent) kernel completes in about 12 seconds:
# time ./t225 1000000
iter: 1000000

real    0m12.306s
user    0m10.155s
sys     0m2.080s
#

